なくていいのか: How to take it?
"あいつ、到着時間はいつだとか、早く行かなくていいのかとか、 うるさかったんだ"
The character is in charge of meeting a friend to the airport and is recalling what his brother told himself. From context I can gather that he's saying "My brother keep complains and asking me when it's the arrival time."
But how is 行かなくていいのか suppose to be read? "行かなくていい" is just "it's ok to not go early" but it sounds wrong?
